# SQL query - sum and get top 5 results

Tags: sql

I need to find the **top 5 players with the most total AST**.

Desired result:

```
PlayerID   Sum(AST)  
3           10  
1           6  
2           5
```

My two tables:

```
tblPlayers   
PlayerID  
1  
2  
3  
4  
5  


tblIndStats  
GameID PlayerID AST  
1       2        2  
2       2        4  
3       3        5  
4       3        5
```

Comment: What DBMS are you using? Oracle, Sql Server?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) Stackoverflow is a Q&A site, not a free code writing service.

Comment: specify DBMS when asking query level questions

Comment: I'm amazed that people prepend tables with `tbl`. I always think of calling them: "Hey person John, how're you doing?"

Answer (score 2):

For Sql Server

```
SELECT TOP 5
    PlayerID, SUM(AST) ASTSUM
FROM tblIndStats
GROUP BY PlayerID
ORDER BY ASTSUM DESC
```

Answer (score 2):

This should get you top 5 in **Microsoft SQL Server**:

```
select top 5 PlayerID, sum(AST) as SumAST
from tblIndStats
group by PlayerID
order by SumAST desc --, PlayerID
```

**Running example**: Here's a [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/57ff0/10) showing results. Example shows the top 5, top 5 extended as well as all results for reference.

### A different problem - several players on fifth place

But there's a different question here as well. What if your last (fifth) record is shared among several players? Say that 3 of them have the same AST sum. Which one would you include in the result then? My example fiddle data shows such a scenario as there are three players that all have `SumAST = 3`.

#### WITH TIES to the rescue

For such cases you can use `with ties` in SQL Server that will automatically include all records that match last place so you wouldn't forget about any player that should as well be honoured (fair play baby). ;)

```
select top 5 with ties PlayerID, sum(AST) as SumAST
from tblIndStats
group by PlayerID
order by SumAST desc
```

Comment: Another solution to the problem would be to use `WITH TIES` to return 7 results as the last 3 are tied. [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/57ff0/8)

Comment: @GarethD: Exactly! I included that in my answer and updated your update of my fiddle because full result wasn't included in results pane.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle:

```
SELECT *
    FROM (
            SELECT PlayerId, SUM(AST)
              FROM tblIndStats S
          GROUP BY PlayerId
          ORDER BY SUM(AST) DESC
          )
    WHERE ROWNUM <= 5
```

SQL Server:

```
SELECT TOP(5) *
    FROM (
            SELECT PlayerId, SUM(AST)
              FROM tblIndStats S
          GROUP BY PlayerId
          ORDER BY SUM(AST) DESC
          )
```

My Sql:

```
SELECT *
    FROM (
            SELECT PlayerId, SUM(AST)
              FROM tblIndStats S
          GROUP BY PlayerId
          ORDER BY SUM(AST) DESC
          )
   LIMIT 5
```

Comment: SQL-Server solution is wrong (and won't run), the order by should be outside the subquery. In the MySQL solution would also be better with the Order by outside of the subquery. Finally, in all three solutions the aggregate column within the subquery needs an alias.

Comment: Why would one resort to subqueries in the first place when there's no need for them? *(except for Oracle that is AFAIK)*

Answer (score -1):

(top type of construct may be database-specific)

```
select playerID, sum(AST)
from tblIndStats
group by playerID
order by sum(AST) desc
```

You don't show any other columns from tblPlayers, so not sure what you want from that table.

Comment: @Cris: it surely is an answer, but it definitely isn't the solution. ;)